# Magento 2 Get Helper Of Default Magento Shipping

Tags: magento2, shipping

I suppose I need to find Helper/Data method to get Magento Shipping->Ship To Specific Countries selected countries list. Where do I find it?

Comment: For which shipping method?

Comment: Default Magento shipping

Comment: There are more than one shipping method then for which method you want this? For different method code will be different.

Comment: When going to admin panel Stores->Configuration->Sales->Shipping Methods->Magento Shipping->Ship to applicable countries->Specific countries. Then theres drop down menu of all countries from which you can choose. And I need to get a list of those selected countries for my custom module.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a helper under your module like below:

> app/code/Vendor/Module/Helper/Data.php

with below code:

```
<?php
namespace Vendor\Module\Helper;
use \Magento\Framework\App\Helper\AbstractHelper;

class Data extends AbstractHelper
{
    protected $scopeConfig;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface $scopeConfig
    ){
      $this->scopeConfig = $scopeConfig;
    }

    public function getSpecificCountries()
    {
        return $this->scopeConfig->getValue('carriers/temando/specificcountry', \Magento\Store\Model\ScopeInterface::SCOPE_STORE);
    }
}
```

To retrieve the value in block class, use the below code:

```
protected $helperData;

public function __construct(
    ....
    \Vendor\Module\Helper\Data $helperData,
    ....
) {
    ....
    $this->helperData = $helperData;
    ....
}

public function getSpecificCountries()
{
    return $this->helperData->getSpecificCountries();
}
```

Now you can call the block function **getSpecificCountries()** in your phtml file like below:

```
print_r($block->getSpecificCountries());
```